# Accessing H2 database schema

Tags: java, schema, h2, information-schema, jooq

Im currently accessing an embedded H2 database in java using [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org) to generate table classes etc. I can currently execute queries such as

```
create.select().from(TEST).fetch()
```

in my code, return results etc.

However I cant query the information schema. I can access it ok using the H2 console, and creating a view for a given information_schema table works fine. My question is how should I be accessing the information_schema eg to perform a query such as

```sql
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

from within my java code? Do I have to create a view, can the schema be accessed through jooq-meta or some other means, or do I need to add something to the property file used  by jooq-codegen (information_schema isn't created in the generated tables classes)? Or something else?

---

Edit:
This is my first foray into using jooq and am coming from a MySQL background. What I'm effectively trying to achieve is to be able to run some unit tests to ensure DB related code works. So I want to access the database's metadata (schema) and return something without having to know if any user created tables exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate classes for the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` just as any other schema. In fact, jOOQ-meta contains some of those classes required for reverse-engineering your database schema.

The [manual's section about advanced code generation properties](http://www.jooq.org/manual/META/AdvancedConfiguration/#N10655) mentions how you can configure the code generator to load several "input schemata":

```xml
<database>
  <schemata>
    <schema>
      <inputSchema>...</inputSchema>
    </schema>
    [ <schema>...</schema> ... ]
  </schemata>
</database>
```

Comment: Ok, I modified my properties file to load multiple schemata and the code-gen successfully created the appropriate classes for them. However when running queries intended for the 2nd schema, SQL table not found errors would occur (even with the appropriate Factory). So far I've only been able to get queries to work if I change the default schema with a factory.use(). Does this sound about right or am I missing the point?

Comment: @user1615803: Can you maybe ask another question showing what you have now? This one here is about generating code for the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`. The other would be about querying the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`. For a future visitor of this question, it might be easier to follow what's going on

Comment: Thanks for the help. Ive submitted a new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070934/querying-the-appropriate-database-schema)