# how to get table structure for h2 database using metadata

Tags: java, metadata, h2, sonarqube

I have written java code to connect to H2 database(sonar's default database) and using metadata I can see all tables and columns for each table. But I want to see table structure(like Primary key, foreign key, number of records in table). How can I view table structure using metadata? or Is there any other approach for viewing table structure?

Solution/help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: This may help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066043/accessing-h2-database-schema

Comment: My 2 cents: I don't know what you're trying to achieve, but 1/ H2 must only be used for testing purposes, 2/ directly touching the DB can have **LOTS** of side effects, and most importantly 3/ the DB is **NOT** an API and can/will therefore change without notice. So 99.99% of the time, it is really a **bad idea** to connect directly to the DB - whatever you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Usually this is done using a (GUI) client: http://h2database.com/html/links.html#tools

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing H2 database schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066043/accessing-h2-database-schema)

Comment: @MatejJ That question is specifically about jOOQ.

Answer (score 9):

```sql
show columns from table_name;
```

This will show you the data type of columns, primary key, initial values etc.